# gtkmm - error message from gtk::appchooserdialog

Tags: gtkmm

Here is the code..

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gio::File> file = Gio::File::create_for_path(filepath);
Gtk::AppChooserDialog *dialog = new Gtk::AppChooserDialog(file, *this);

if ( dialog->run() == Gtk::RESPONSE_OK ) {
    Glib::RefPtr<Gio::AppInfo> appinfo = dialog->get_app_info();
    appinfo->launch(file);
}
dialog->hide();
```

This is the message i get when the above code is executed..

```
glibmm-WARNING **: Glib::ConstructParams::ConstructParams(): object class "gtkmm__GtkAppChooserDialog" has no property named "file"
```

I'm probably making a silly mistake here. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Well, in gtk-3.0, there is no GtkAppChooserDialog property named "file", but there is a property named "gfile".  This appears to be a bug in the [gtkmm wrapping](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkmm/tree/gtk/src/appchooserdialog.ccg) where "file" should have been "gfile" in the appropriate _CONSTRUCT() call (currently line 38 and 44), but I don't have enough wrapper understanding to be sure.  If this is the problem, I don't see an easy workaround without patching gtkmm.

**Update**: It was [a bug](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkmm/commit/gtk/src/appchooserdialog.ccg?id=70d92a106ab7aea5f25fcc0ee69edc181ef8a157) in the wrapping.